# Why do some characters lose when I use str_shuffle() in PHP?

Tags: php, string, special-characters, shuffle

This is the code in lib.php:

```
<?php

class table {

    function __construct($string, $time) {

        $out = '<table cellpadding="5">';
        $out .= $this->getRow('th', 'Nom., Shuffled String, Lenght');

        for ($x = 1; $x <= $time; $x++) {

            $shuffledStr = str_shuffle($string); //Maybe this causes the problem
            $shuffledStr_len = strlen($shuffledStr);
            $out .= $this->getRow('td', $x . ', ' . $shuffledStr . ', ' . $shuffledStr_len);
        }

        $out .= '</table>';

        echo $out;
    }

    public function getRow($tagName, $contents_list) {

        //Variables:
        $out = '';
        $contents_array = explode(', ', $contents_list);
        $contents_number = count($contents_array);
        $start_tag = '<' .  $tagName . '>';
        $end_tag = '</' .   $tagName . '>';

        // Build
        $out .= '<tr>';

        for ($i = 0; $i < $contents_number; $i++) {
            $out .= $start_tag . $contents_array[$i] . $end_tag;
        }

        $out .= '</tr>';

        return $out;
    }

}
?>
```

And here is index.php:

```
    <?php
require_once 'lib.php';
$string = ''; //My string
$shuffleTimes = 100;
$table = new table($string, $shuffleTimes);
?>
```

This program gets the a string and the number that you wanna shuffle, 
then create a table and returns the number, shuffled string and the length of the shuffle string in each row.

If I set the variable `$string` to 'Stack Overflow' for instance it'll work correctly (It shuffles this word 100 times randomly, returns all lengths 14 and the length of the **ALL** shuffled strings are really 14.)

But...

If I add some special character to the variable `$string` (for example `Stack Overflow+_)(*&^%$#{}[]<>@!~./=-`) it won't work correctly. That means it returns the lengths 37 But they doesn't have 37 characters!(For example it printed `nothing` and printed it's lenght `38`.
I think it's a bit strange. :(

Why is that?! Which character causes that and how to fix it?

Comment: `Stack Overflow+_)(*&^%$#{}[]<>@!~./=-` is 37 char length...?

Comment: Yes, it is. Isn't it?

Comment: You said `But they doesn't have 37 characters!`. What now? Does it have 37 or not? p.s. your code works for me. it only doesnt work for multibyte characters.

Comment: It returns `NOTHING` and also returns it has 37 characters. What are "multibyte" characters? Can you explain or give a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code.

#### 1. getRow() issue :

The problem is in `getRow()`, where you concat parameters into one string with `,`, and then explode by `,`. If your string has `,` inside it, then you will have problems, example: `Stack ,test`.

#### 2. multibyte issue :

This code doesn't work for multibyte characters. To accomplish that you will need to change function `str_shuffle()` with function bellow `mb_str_shuffle()`, and `strlen()` with `mb_strlen()`.

```
function mb_str_shuffle($str) {
    $tmp = preg_split("//u", $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    shuffle($tmp);
    return join("", $tmp);
}
```

Or some other unicode function that you find in comments on http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-shuffle.php

#### 3. length is ok, but string is missing issue :

This is because you have HTML special chars in your string, like `<` and `>`. If string `Stack Overflow+_)(*&^%$#{}[]<>@!~./=-` is shuffled, and you get something like `a#^&/c-_O.` instead of `a#^&/c-_O.< ~*>)$wevS+{(%}klr[]f=to!@`. You should escape special chars with [htmlspecialchars()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) when you output the string.

Comment: Thank you for your reminding about `htmlspecialchars()`. The strings should process without escaping because escaping increase the legnth of the string. The string must be escaped before it displays. (The problem was on line 14 of lib.php It should change to `   $out .= $this->getRow('td', $x . ', ' . htmlspecialchars($shuffledStr) . ', ' . $shuffledStr_len);` SOLVED :)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a problem with Encoding.

Have you tried using a function, that handles encoding right?

try this: (copied from PHP Manual)

```
function unicode_shuffle($string, $chars, $format = 'UTF-8')
{
    for($i=0; $i<$chars; $i++)
        $rands[$i] = rand(0, mb_strlen($string, $format));

        $s = NULL;

    foreach($rands as $r)
        $s.= mb_substr($string, $r, 1, $format);

    return $s;
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work. If you want that, do this: 
function unicode_shuffle($string, $chars, $format = 'UTF-8')
{
    return mb_substr(str_shuffle_unicode($string), 0, $chars, $format);
    
}